# UWP clear translucent window possible?

Tags: uwp

Is clear translucency possible with a UWP application, something like below possible?

[image]

NOT, blurred translucency (so-called acrylic) like this.

[image]

Comment: Hello, currently UWP does not provide related APIs to set the transparency of the window.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as part of UWP, but it is possible to use underlaying Windows APIs, `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` of `user32`. Please see this example project:
[Github castorix/WinUI3_Transparent](https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_Transparent)

Furthermore, there are discussions and considerations in various repos:

[ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar & SetTitleBar make TitleBar unusable](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6993),
[Proposal: Layered window and full Transparent window for UWP apps.](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/173)